# What are the building blocks of matter?

Tags: atoms

**Question 1:** If atoms are made up of fundamental particles, then why we say that atoms are the building blocks of matter?

> Atom, the basic building block of all matter. ([1](https://www.britannica.com/science/atom))

> Atoms are the basic units of matter. ([2](https://www.livescience.com/37206-atom-definition.html))

> The atom is considered the basic building block of matter. ([3](https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/basic-ref/students/science-101/what-is-an-atom.html))

**Question 2:** Is it right to say that fundamental particles are the building blocks of matter?

Comment: Gosh, golly, I thought building blocks are what kids play ;> Oh, it must be one of these, whatchamcallit, *metaphors*! But better get to the source. Building blocks of kids' constructions are... building blocks, aren't they? And they are certainly made from smaller stuff, yet they *are* building blocks, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Mithoron Your chagrin is understandable but this seems a reasonable and researched question. The focus is on definitions that play a bit too loosely with language. The OP is right to question them. What you write as a comment is part of the answer. A complete answer would address the history of seeking (the why) and the identity (the what) of the smallest division  of matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elementary particles are building blocks on physical level, atoms on chemical level.

The smallest particle of a chemical element is an element atom. The smallest  particle of a chemical compound is a compound molecule.

But the currently smallest particles of baryonic matter are quarks, electrons and virtual particles of force interactions.

Comment: Force carrier aren't necessarily virtual.

Comment: @Mithoron They are not, but such are not necessarily present.